# C - How to declare procedure with matrix (multi array) parameter

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, declaration, procedure

I want to declare procedure with matrix parameter. But I get error. How to declare matrix parameter ?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    //I get error when I declare this
    void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [][]);

    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int _papanSudoku[9][9]) {

    }
```

[image]

Comment: `void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [9][9]);` or `void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [][9]);` or `void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int (*)[9]);`. BTW, whenever you post a question about a piece of code that gives an error,**Post the error message**. We aren't compilers, you know

Comment: You should answer not comment

Answer (score 4):

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [9][9]);
```

or

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [][9]);
```

or

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int (*)[9]);
```

are the right ways to declare the function prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You can only skip the first part of a two dimensional array, so change it to

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int [][9]);
                             ^
                            you can skip a value here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify dimensions, you can use VLA's ([Variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int, int(*)[]);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int size, int (*_papanSudoku)[size]) {

}
```

Call it using:

```
solvingSudokuPuzzle(9, arr);
```

But the correct way is:

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int (*_papanSudoku)[9]) {
```

or

```
void solvingSudokuPuzzle(int _papanSudoku[][9]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If size is not fixed, then use a double pointer  like:

```
(int **myMatrix)
```